# ASP.NET MVC 4 Trigger Error Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have been looking for a way to define my own errors in ASP.NET MVC4 using C#. For example, say I have a C# file where I encounter an exception. I would like to trigger the [ASP.NET default error page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/error-default.png) and fill the title and description in with my own error.

To clarify, I am not looking to create a custom error page, as I already know how to do that. Instead, I want to trigger and display my own error message on the default ASP.NET error page. I would like to avoid throwing an exception and never catch it, as I feel that might be a corny way of making ASP.NET choke.

Can anyone show me how I can trigger the error page?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this by adding this into Global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;

   var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
}
```

You will get all the details in "currentRouteData" then you can do whatever you want to do with this errors.